# Loading Bitmaps efficiently - still getting out of memory error

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I was getting out of memory errors loading custom images. I read https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html for assistance.

I'm following the example to decode the stream to get size information first, then decode. Still crashing on that first decoding. Is there a way around this?

ava.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 48771084 byte allocation with 16776928 free bytes and 25MB until OOM
BackgroundImageManager.java, line 84

dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray  Native Method
2   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream   Native Method
3   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal BitmapFactory.java, line 882
4   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream BitmapFactory.java, line 858
5   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream BitmapFactory.java, line 896
6   com.myapp.Utils.BackgroundImageManager.background   BackgroundImageManager.java, line 8

```
public class BackgroundImageManager {
    private final static String TAG = BackgroundImageManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private static InputStream currentBackgroundImage;

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        Log.v("Biscuit-Sample", String.valueOf(inSampleSize));
        if (inSampleSize < 4) {
            inSampleSize = 4;
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Drawable background(Context context, Store store) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        String bgUri = null;
        int bgId = 0;
        if (store != null) {
            bgUri = store.backgroundImageURI;
            bgId = store.backgroundImageNumber;
        }

        if (currentBackgroundImage != null) {
            try {
                currentBackgroundImage.close();
                Log.v(TAG, "Current background image closed.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close background image.", e);
            }
        }

        if(bgUri != null && !bgUri.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int width = size.x;
                int height = size.y;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream( context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(bgUri)) );
                options.inSampleSize = BackgroundImageManager.calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(bgUri)) );
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
                return d;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Custom background image file could not be found.", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close custom background image after creating drawable", e);
            }
        }
        if(bgId != 0) {
            try {
                return context.getResources().getDrawable(bgId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_default);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle bitmpas you can use one of the many opensource libraries available. E.g [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/)

to your issue:

First you are decoding the same bitmap twice.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream( context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(bgUri)) );
options.inSampleSize = BackgroundImageManager.calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(bgUri)) );
```

It is probably a wrong copy/paste. In the first line the bitmap is decode and not used. Delete the first  `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`

the problem lies here

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(bgUri)) );
```

it should be

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(bgUri)), null, options);
```

the option's object has to be part of the method's call in order to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to manage images is with the Picasso library because it manages cache and ram, and therefore avoiding `OutOfMemory` crash.

Example: `Picasso.with(Context).load("your_url").into(yourImageView);`

More info here:
[Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: @an_android_dev will I have to open an input stream, or can I jus use Uri.parse(bgUri) instead of "your_url"?

Comment: @quantumpotato you can use url String. For example : load("http://example.com/myimage.jpeg");

Comment: @an_android_dev I will try this. The URI I have is local to the device